# Image and SVG overlapping inconsistently

Tags: css, svg, position

I have images which I would like to overlap a number of animated SVGs on my website. I am finding it difficult to make this work in a responsive way. At a browser width of approx 1400px the img and svg are overlapped in the correct way (see attached screenshot). However once the browser is wider or narrower then the two elements scale and reposition independently and in a manner that means they are soon misaligned.

Is there any way I can fix these two elements together so that they always have the positional relationship at 1400px (at least on desktop)?

I have tried working with absolute/relative and a 1x1 grid to make this work but no luck.

Website [here](https://meta-draft.superhi.com/about.html).
[image]

Comment: you may put the image inside the svg using the `<image>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Just embed the image inside the svg using the image tag. An easy way to do this is using Inkscape. You open the image in Inkscape and select the link or embed option. Later I will explain that. Once in the image is in Inkscape you open the svg and position it in the right spot where you like. After that you save the whole as a svg file.

Later on you may have to clean the svg using SVGO (there is a great online service hosted in github.com). Once cleaned you just have to load the svg in your page.

The opening options when you open an image in Inkscape are to embed or link the image. What's the difference? When you embed the image it is converted to a base 64 string which will reside inside the svg making it bigger in weight. If you link the image then the svg file will be much lighter.

The pros and cons of each approach:
When you embed the image inside the svg you'll get a massive unique file. That's very convenient in some many ways.

When you link the image then you have to take into account that the img must reside in a folder and if you move the image to another folder then the link will be broken. But anyway you can move the image to whatever folder you want, you just have to open the svg in a text editor and replace the link to point to the actual folder.

The cons on the first option is that if you pretend to embed the svg code inside the html code it will get real big.

The cons of the second option is that you must keep the track of the image folder.

Choose which approach fits your needs and you are done.